# Why are some of my columns of my data not recognized on my data frame after importing a csv file to python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my code

```
Import pandas as pd
finance=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/hp/Desktop/Financial Sample.csv")

finance.Profit.describe()
```

### And the error

> AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)  in  ----> 1 finance.Profit.describe() ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in **getattr**(self, name) 5177 if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name): 5178 return self[name] -> 5179 return object.**getattribute**(self, name) 5180 5181 def **setattr**(self, name, value): AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Profit'

Comment: What is `print (finance.head())` ?

Comment: Is separator `,` ?

Comment: need more info like a sample of a the header and example rows of the csv.

also you can format your code by enveloping them in back ticks

Answer (score 0):

according to your submitted error
here is correct syntax to describe Profit Column

```
finance['Profit'].describe()
```

Answer (score 0):

This syntax will work if the column name has been parsed as how it was saved (case-sensitive):

```
finance['Profit'].describe()
```

However, sometimes the name of your column can have added characters before it after reading so the actual call might result in an error. To avoid this, you can also use `.iloc()`

```
finance.iloc[:,"(column number here, starts from 0)"].describe()
```